# CIFS Fileshare 'randomly' cycling through different combinations of attributes

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

Would appreciate any assistance here, I have a file share (WD EX4100 NAS) on my docker host (Ubuntu 18.08.4 LTS - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-123-generic x86_64)) that has been working until recently, now my files appear to be cycling through random patterns of attributes causing other issues with read / modify access for other systems, etc... due to the immutable flag.

Notice the timestamps

> [15:17:38] administrator@ubuntu-container_host:/media/plexarex/share$ lsattr
> s-S-i-dAc-jI------ ./test.txt
> s-S-i-dAc-jI------ ./test2.txt
> [15:17:41] administrator@ubuntu-container_host:/media/plexarex/share$ lsattr
> ----iad-c-jI------ ./test.txt
> ----iad-c-jI------ ./test2.txt
> [15:17:42] administrator@ubuntu-container_host:/media/plexarex/share$ lsattr
> ----iad---jI------ ./test.txt
> ----iad---jI------ ./test2.txt
> [15:17:43] administrator@ubuntu-container_host:/media/plexarex/share$ lsattr
> s-S-i-d-c-jI------ ./test.txt
> s-S-i-d-c-jI------ ./test2.txt
> [15:17:43] administrator@ubuntu-container_host:/media/plexarex/share$ lsattr
> su----d-c-jI------ ./test.txt
> su----d-c-jI------ ./test2.txt
> [15:17:44] administrator@ubuntu-container_host:/media/plexarex/share$ lsattr
> s---i---c-jI------ ./test.txt
> s---i---c-jI------ ./test2.txt

/etc/fstab entry

```
//192.168.1.30/plexarex /media/plexarex cifs rw,noacl,nouser_xattr,credentials=/home/fileshare_svc/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=fileshare_svc,gid=fileshare_svc 0 0
```

Troubleshooting steps / Things I've tried:

1. Disabled all containers
2. Attempted to overwrite with chattr
3. Recreated share
4. Unmapped share from all other locations
5. Changed /etc/fstab (added noacl, nouser_xattr)

Looking for ideas here, I don't know what else to try, I've never ran into this before and am unsure on where to go / what to try next.

Comment: You don't mention your version of Ubuntu. In 18.04 I have an SMB share which works perfectly well after cifs with username=xxx,password=xxx,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 (appreciating that you are using smbcredentials)...

Comment: Thanks, just added that info to the post.  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-123-generic x86_64)